# Jumping issue when changing the custom keyboard height

Tags: ios, ios-keyboard-extension

I am able to change the custom keyboard height but when i am changing the keyboard height first it setting to default keyboard height and jumping back to the given height.
please help me out in this.

Comment: Please provide some code of how you change the height. This will make it a lot easier to help you.

Comment: I am changing the height constraint as it is like given in the apple developer site.

Answer (score 0):

Per the docs: "In iOS 8.0, you can adjust a custom keyboard’s height any time *after* its primary view initially draws on screen." It is impossible to solve the jumping issue.

Comment: Thanks for Reply. But how other people are doing like SwiftKey. And is there any document to "It is impossible to solve the jumping issue".

Comment: This *is* the documentation. The height can't be set until after the keyboard has appeared. If you draw your keyboard at the original height, and then at the new height, it will appear to bounce. You could have a hackish solution that waits for the keyboard height to be set to what you want before it draws the full keyboard, but I wouldn't recommend it -- some apps will not respect your height constraint, and you will receive no callback to layout your subviews. Swiftkey actually fails spectacularly in these apps. Try SwiftKey in Steam, see what happens.

Comment: Thanks Ben. Could you please explain me the hacking solution, any sample code would be great helpful for me. I need to resolve the jumping issue at any cost.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the height in the `viewWillAppear` of your keyboard (the one you are inheriting from `UIInputViewController`).